# Refresh cached values in spark streaming without reboot the batch

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Maybe the question is too simple, at least look like that, but I have the following problem:

A. Execute spark submit in spark streaming process.

```
 ccc.foreachRDD(rdd => {
          rdd.repartition(20).foreachPartition(p => {

               val repo = getReposX
               t foreach (g => {
    .................
```

B. getReposX is a function which one make a query in mongoDB recovering a Map wit a key/value necessary in every executor of the process.

C. Into each g in foreach I manage this map "cached"

The problem or the question is when in the collection of mongo anything change, I don't watch or I don't detect the change, therefore I am managing a Map not updated. My question is: How can I get it?  Yes, I know If I reboot the spark-submit and the driver is executed again is OK but otherwise I will never see the update in my Map.

Any ideas or suggestion?
Regards.

Comment: Is repo an RDD? If it so you can simply `unpersist` it by some condition.

Comment: No, It is a Map, but I am not sure about your answer, becausein that case what condition could you use to realize anything change in the collection?

The question or my target is, where should I put the getRepo in my code, without forget this is a streaming process and I cant reboot the driver, for the process get the changes of this map in every mini-batch executed by spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Developed a solution. First I explain the question more in detail because what I really wanted to know is how to implement an object or "cache", which was refreshed every so often, or by some kind of order, without the need to restart the spark streaming process, that is, it would refresh in alive.

In my case this "cache" or refreshed object is an object (Singleton) that connected to a collection of mongoDB to recover a HashMap that was used by each executor and was cached in memory as a good Singleton. The problem with this was that once the spark streaming submit is executed it was cached that object in memory but it was not refreshed unless the process was restarted. Think of a broadcast as a counter mode to refresh when the variable reaches 1000, but these are read only and can not be modified. Think of an counter, but these can only be read by the driver.

Finally my solution is, within the initialization block of the object that loads the mongo collection and the cache, I implement this:

```
    //Initialization Block
      {
          val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
          val task = new Runnable {
            def run() = {
              logger.info("Refresh - Inicialization")
              initCache
            }
          }
          val f = ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, TIME_REFRES, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       }


initCache is nothing more than a function that connects mongo and loads a collection:

    var cache = mutable.HashMap[String,Description]()
    def initCache():mutable.HashMap[String, Description]={
           val serverAddresses = Functions.getMongoServers(SERVER, PORT)

        val mongoConnectionFactory = new MongoCollectionFactory(serverAddresses,DATABASE,COLLECTION,USERNAME,PASSWORD)

        val collection = mongoConnectionFactory.getMongoCollection()

        val docs = collection.find.iterator()
        cache.clear()
        while (docs.hasNext) {

          var doc = docs.next

          cache.put(...............
        }

        cache
      }
```

In this way, once the spark streaming submit has been started, each task will open one more task, which will make every X time (1 or 2 hours in my case) refresh the value of the singleton collection, and always recover that value instantiated:

```
def getCache():mutable.HashMap[String, Description]={
      cache
}
```